# ¿Es el uso de "explicar" como "contar" un catalanismo?

Tags: verbos, modismos, diferencias-regionales, catalán

En algunos casos he leído u oído frases que usan el verbo *explicar* en el mismo sentido en el que se usa *contar*:

> Explícame una historia, y así me dormiré.
>   Va, explícanos un chiste.

Este uso lo tengo yo asociado a un catalanismo. En el caso de la primera frase expuesta como ejemplo, se dice en la película [Porco Rosso](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104652/), que fue traducida para España por un estudio de Barcelona. Aunque entiendo que "explicar" es, a fin de cuentas, "contar algo con detalle" o "de forma clara", las acepciones de *[explicar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HJbpHBZ)* no cuadran exactamente con lo que se quiere expresar en los ejemplos. El caso es que siempre me ha sonado muy raro este uso, sobre todo el ejemplo del chiste, ya que un chiste solo se explica después de contarlo y si alguien no lo entiende. Y siempre que he leído u oído frases así ha sido siempre por parte de un catalán o a través de una traducción hecha por un catalán. Así que quería preguntar:

- ¿Está este uso de "explicar" restringido a Cataluña o se usa en más sitios de España?
- Si efectivamente está restringido a Cataluña, ¿está influenciado por cómo se expresa la misma frase en catalán? ¿O es un modismo en español que se ha generado allí sin relación con el catalán?

Comment: @walen ignoro cómo se dicen en catalán (es una de mis preguntas). La razón es simplemente que siempre se la he oído a un catalán o leído a través de una traducción o texto escrito por un catalán. Lo he añadido a la pregunta.

Comment: En los diccionarios de catalán las definiciones de la palabra *explicar* son las mismas que en castellano y contar es: *Explicar amb detall una cosa real o inventada*. Se añade lo de "con detalle" que es un matiz del que carece en castellano. Creo que siempre he oido decir a los catalanes tanto en castellano como en catalán *explicar* y nunca o casi nunca *contar*. Al menos los de Barcelona que es donde conozco gente.

Comment: Sí, yo solo lo he oído en Cataluña.

Answer (score 6):

Yo personalmente nunca lo he escuchado y si me pidieses explicar una historia o un cuento, pensaría que tuvieses alguna duda de por qué algo ocurrió o de qué era la moraleja o mensaje que pretendía.

He aquí algunos datos para ver si podemos aclarar la fuente y el uso de la frase:

```
+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|    Catalán     |   conta un conte   |  explica un conte   |
|   Valenciano   |        2.080       |       21.900        |
+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|  Castellano    |  cuenta un cuento  |  explica un cuento  |
|    Español     |       237.000      |       26.000        |
+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|   Asturiano    |  cuenta un cuentu  |  esplica un cuentu  |
|                |         200        |          1          |
+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|   Portugués    |   conta um conto   |  explica um conto   |
|    Gallego     |       127.000      |          4          |
+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|    Francés     |  raconte un conte  |  explique un conte  |
|                |       401.000      |         8.600       |
+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
|    Italiano    | racconta una storia|  spiega una storia  |
|                |       401.000      |        17.000       |
+----------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Casi todos los resultados en castellano eran de España o hablaban de cosas publicadas en España (y sobre todo de editoriales en Cataluña, como se nota con el libro *40 animales explican un cuento*), o eran resultados falsos (tipo *alguien explica, «un cuento…»*).  La forma predominante en catalán/valenciano es con *explica* y no con *conta*.  Los únicos resultados en italiano parece que refieren a dar explicaciones o razonamientos debido al uso de *storia* (con *racconta* los resultados son 7 y 0 para *racconta* y *spiega*).  El único resultado en asturiano habla de un programa televisivo catalán, por lo que podría tratar de una interferencia (conozco personalmente el hombre que lo escribió, y habla catalán también).  Los resultados en francés son interesantes porque  muchos de los con *explique* ¡eran de páginas en catalán!  Lo que de verdad me sorprende es la falta total de resultados en portugués y gallego con *explica* (combiné los resultados porque las formas son idénticas), pero así fue.

En fin, creo que podemos decir que, sea el uso que sea en castellano, vino más probablemente del catalán/valenciano. No sé bien determinar los usos dentro de España (¿tal vez con Twitter se podría buscar según localización?), pero imagino que los usos serían principalmente en Cataluña, Valencia y las Islas Baleares porque si no, yo habría escuchado la construcción y recordádola porque sigue sonándome muy extraña, la verdad.

Comment: En catalán el presente de la tercera persona singular de *contar* es *conta* y no *compte* que es *cuenta* pero como sustantivo. No se si en valenciano es distinto

Comment: @blonfu ups, voy a buscarlo de nuevo

Comment: @blonfu solo lo demuestra con más claridad ;-)

Comment: No cabe duda que *explicar un cuento* es un catalanismo pero me parece que *contar* es sin embargo mas utilizado en catalán que lo que sugieren la cifras de la tabla anterior. Mejor comparar *conta'm un conto* con *explica'm un conto*.

Comment: @jlliagre: En forma imperativa (bueno, quizás puede ser indicativo en catalán, no sé bien dónde se ponen por omisión los pronombres átonos en él), los resultados son más igualitarios en catalán-valenciano, y muchos más distinguidos en castellano:  *conta'm un conte* aparece 68.200 veces, y *explica'm un conte* 45.500, frente a 540.000 de "cuéntame un cuento" y 1.620 por "explícame un cuento".

Comment: En catalán tenemos tres palabras homófonas: conte, comte y compte. Conte = cuento, comte = conde, compte = cuenta. _Compte amb el conte del comte_ = _ve con cuidado con el cuento del conde_. Por ende, _contar_ es para explicar, pero _comptar_ para contar (dinero, etc.).